# React Aria/ NextUIHow to Activate Dropdown Menu on Hover

Tags: reactjs, nextui, react-aria

How can I actiavte a React Aria / NextUI Dropdown Menu on hover?

This is the Dropdown Menu API: https://nextui.org/docs/components/dropdown#usage which I assume is based on React Aria's Menu https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/Menu.html

There are "Trigger" components, but it's unclear how to activate the menu. There is an event fired supposedly `onMouseEnter`, but then how can I set a variable to activate the menu?

`<DropdownTrigger onMouseEnter={}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** that this is not in the docs and the docs are wrong for both [NextUI](https://nextui.org/docs/components/dropdown#usage) and [Aria](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/Menu.html#menutrigger)!!! As you can see in the Aria link above, the property is listed in MenuTrigger, but it's actually available in the Menu component...

**Answer**

The `Dropdown` component has a prop called `isOpen` which can be passed a boolean to control the state of the menu.

So you can make a state variable

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
```

And then pass it to the prop. Further you can use the `onMouseLeave` and `onMouseEnter` props to control behaviour. Note that these are not documented and that you have to use the onMouseLeave in the `Dropdown` component and `onMouseEnter` on the `DropdownTrigger` component, otherwise the behaviour breaks.

```js
<Dropdown
          placement="bottom"
          isOpen={isOpen}
          onMouseLeave={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        >
          <DropdownTrigger onMouseEnter={() => setIsOpen(true)}>
```